# Changing Libgdx Button appearance

Tags: java, android, button, drawable, libgdx

I need to be able to change the appearance of a Libgdx `Button` when some of my events are triggered.

Here is the declaration of my button:

`Button googleButton = new Button(skin.getDrawable("google_sign_in"));`

Here are the things I tried:

```
googleButton.setBackground(skin.getDrawable("google_sign_out"));
googleButton.invalidate();

googleButton.setChecked(true);
googleButton.invalidate();

googleButton.getStyle().up = skin.getDrawable("google_sign_out");
googleButton.invalidate();
```

I have done a lot of searches but I can't find the answer. Could somebody show me the right way of doing this?

Comment: The problem is I don't want it to change its appearance upon up and down events, it is events that don't have a link with the button itself that need to switch its image.

Comment: I need to be able to change the picture, not to have the same. Maybe I do not need to use a button, what type of actor should I use to be able to change its image on the fly?

Comment: could you post the "google_sign_in" style as well?

Comment: It's not a style, it's a drawable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're changing the contents of the skin/style after initializing the `Button`, but the button object does not reference the style after it has been initialized.  I'm also not entirely clear on what you're going for.  I assume you want to show a "sign in" button, until the user is signed in, and then you want that button to be a "sign out" button.

The `invalidate` method just triggers a re-layout (to re-compute the size/location of the `Actor`).

Maybe try forcing the style with `setStyle`, like this:

```
   googleButton.getStyle().up = ... whatever;
   googleButton.setStyle(googleButton.getStyle());
```

That said, I think you would be better off having two (?) different `Button` objects (one for logging in, and one for logging out).  Pack them in a [Stack](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Stack.html), and just make one or the other invisible (see [`Actor.setVisible`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setVisible(boolean)))

Comment: I already tried setting the style after it was initialized, but it does nothing. Sincerely, the Stack is completely useless, it is just a Vector, it won't change the z index of the elements in it... I managed to change the button visible by switching the visibility of both buttons like you proposed. I just hoped there was a way of doing this with only 1 actor.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this to work. In my Actor, a dice that have 6 possible images:

```
public Dice(int options) {
    super(new Button.ButtonStyle());
}
```

And when I want to change the face:

```
public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    Button.ButtonStyle style = getStyle();
    style.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(
            Assets.instance.dices.facesUp[value]);
    style.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(
            Assets.instance.dices.facesDown[value]);
    style.checked = new TextureRegionDrawable(
            Assets.instance.dices.facesChecked[value]);
    setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
}
```

I think the trick is at the

```
setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
```

If I omit it, the dice doesn't get displayed. And there's no need for setStyle or invalidate().

Answer (score 1):

Use [CheckBox](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/CheckBox.html) class instead;

1- make a .json file for the skin

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: fontfile.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 }
  },
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    google-loggin: { checkboxOn: google_sign_in, checkboxOff: google_sign_out, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
}
```

2- make a skin

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("your.json-file.json"), new TextureAtlas("textureAtlas-file.pack"));
```

3- create the button ignoring the first argument:

```
CheckBox loginButton = new CheckBox("", skin, "google-loging");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone searching for this through google. To change the style of the button from a style already added to your skin file, after already initialising:

```
btn.setStyle(skin.get("YOUR BTN STYLE",TextButton.TextButtonStyle.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add image to button `button_1.addActor(image)`. This image will cover the button origin skin. And then you can switch off and on this image `image.setVisible(false)`